# what's the formal way to initialize extern const variable?

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, constants

I'm using a .h file to put all the global variables in one file to make sure all files can access the same value. But i have a const int, I wonder where should I inisilize it?

.h:

```
#ifndef globalVar_H
#define globalVar_H


const int MAXCPU;
const int MAXPreBorder;

#endif
```

.cpp:

```
int MAXCPU=12;
int MAXPreBorder=20;
```

I think I should declare in the .h file and initialize in the .cpp file. But the compiler said:

```
error: non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression
```

If I initialize in the .h file. the compiler would not complain.. I wonder if this is the right way?

.h:

```
#ifndef globalVar_H
#define globalVar_H


const int MAXCPU=12;
const int MAXPreBorder=20;

#endif
```

.cpp:

```
//nothing?
```

Comment: The `const` is part of the type.

Comment: You're not providing enough of the compiler output to correctly analyze the problem. Crystal ball says one of the two names is already used as a #define or macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const` variable is also (by default) `static`, so you have a unique one for each `.cpp` file in which the header is included.

As such, you normally want to initialize it "in place", since the instance defined in one TU won't be the same as the instance you initialized in your source file.

Comment: If I change it to extern, It also need to be initialized in place?

Comment: @weeo: No -- but you rarely want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

globalVar.h:

```
#ifndef globalVar_H
#define globalVar_H


extern const int MAXCPU;
extern const int MAXPreBorder;

#endif
```

globalVar.cpp:

```
const int MAXCPU = 12;
const int MAXPreBorder = 20;
```

Comment: same thing:non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression

Comment: @weeo Can you show the line where those constants are being used in a template?

Comment: @weeo If greatwolf's answer didn't work for you, then either "MAXCPU" or "MAXPreBorder" is a macro or defined elsewhere. See http://ideone.com/lKafPx